# increase snowpipe speed to process 1 record per file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-pipe

I have a snowpipe.  I do not have control over the incoming files.  The files each contain a single, relatively small json record.

The stage had about 38000 files when I restarted the pipe due to an error.
I am currently only processing 6-8 files per minute.
EDIT: Correction, I have processed about 750 files in 55 min.  Still very slow.

How can I speed this up without changing the one record per file constraint?

```json
{
  "id": "55555555-5555-5555-5555-555555555555",
  "val": {
    "bank": "bank name",
    "browser_version": "1.7.4044.138",
    "cpu": "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz",
    "cpu_architecture": "x86_64",
    "created_at": "2020-07-31T10:21:12.992345225Z",
    "current_address": "address",
    "current_city": null,
    "current_country": "my country",
    "date_of_birth": "1990-03-21",
    "document_number": "55-55-55-55555",
    "document_type": "this type of document",
    "email": "some.email@email.com",
    "full_name": "some name",
    "gender": "Male",
    "internal_storage": "237.87 GB",
    "joined_date": "2020-07-31",
    "last_logged_in": null,
    "last_worked_on": "2020-12-02",
    "latitude": "Not Found",
    "longitude": "Not Found",
    "memory": "7.74 GB",
    "number_of_processors": "8",
    "app_client_uid": "{55555555-5LLL-5555-55L5-555B5555DB5A}",
    "operating_system": "win 10.0",
    "other_display": null,
    "id_number": "555555555",
    "permanent_address": null,
    "permanent_city": null,
    "permanent_country": null,
    "personal_email": "anotheremail@gmail.com",
    "primary_display": "1920x1080",
    "role_id": "55555555-5555-5555-5555-555555555555",
    "source_system": [
      {
        "id": "astringidthiny",
        "system": "system_name"
      }
    ],
    "status": "Active",
    "type": "worker",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-02T08:32:56Z",
    "webcam": "true",
    "workstream_ids": [
      "55555555-5555-5555-5555-555555555555"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am writing the data into a table with a single variant column

Comment: Are you using AWS, Azure or GCP?

Comment: @Marcel I'm using AWS